# why custom dialog buttons dont work?

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

I have a custom dialog in my app but when I click on the buttons of dialog they don't work!

I want to show dialog in one of the items of navigation drawer
and that's code:

```
dialog = new Dialog(MaterialCardsActivity.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_mail);
        dialog.show();
```

How can I resolve it?

Custom_Dialog.java

```
package com.example.material.amirj;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Dialog_Custom extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText caption;
private Dialog dialog;
private EditText text;
private Button send,cancel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_mail);


    dialog = new Dialog(Dialog_Custom.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_mail);

    caption = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_caption_dialoge);
    text = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_text_dialoge);
    send = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_send_email);
    cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_dialog);

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"titandevelopers98@gmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "" + caption.getText());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "" + text.getText());
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "ارسال ایمیل با ..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(Dialog_Custom.this, "برنامه ای از ازسال ایمیل پشتیبانی نمیکند.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
  dialog.show();
}
}
```

dialog_mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="ارتباط با ما - ایمیل"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ارسال"
    android:id="@+id/btn_send_email"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="151dp"
    android:theme="@style/MyButton"
    android:allowUndo="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="لغو"
    android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_dialog"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_send_email"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_send_email"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_send_email" />
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyHintText"
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="عنوان"
        android:id="@+id/txt_text_dialoge"
        android:theme="@style/MyEditText" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyHintText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_cancel_dialog">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="متن پیام"
        android:id="@+id/txt_caption_dialoge"
        android:theme="@style/MyEditText" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[final result but buttons don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uivMw.jpg)

Comment: You're never calling `dialog.show()` at the end of your `onCreate`. how are you even seeing this dialog?

Comment: Which button doesn't work? send or cancel?

Comment: Also, are you trying to show a Dialog inside an activity or are you trying to have a small dialog like transparent activity?

Comment: i want to show dialog in navigation drawer item!

Comment: both of them don't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> dialog_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click To Show Custom Dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDialog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDialog"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/okButton"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ok"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textDialog"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDialog"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> CustomDialog.java

public class CustomDialog extends Activity {

```
private Button btnClick;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_main);

    btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);

    // add listener to button 
    buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Create custom dialog object
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CustomDialog.this);
            // Include dialog.xml file
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            // Set dialog title
            dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

            // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
            text.setText("Custom dialog");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageDialog);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image0);

            dialog.show();

            Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
            // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Close dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


        }

    });

  }

}
```

Happy coding..!